# How come node-windows service stops running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, service, node-windows

We have a node-windows service that runs our API.  Sometimes when I start it, it immediately dies for no apparent reason.  I go to restart it and it stops as soon as it starts.  No helpful error messages in event viewer.  Usually un-installing and re-installing the service does the trick, but today it doesn't.

Here's the code:

```html
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;
 
// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name:'Node.js Service Management API',
  description: 'The nodejs.org service management api.',
  script: 'D:\\Program Files\\nodeApps\\service-management-api\\server\\index.js'
});
 
// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
// process is available as a service.
svc.on('install',function(){
  svc.start();
});
 
svc.install();
```

Any clues?